# Docker image is not pushed to AWS ECR repository from CI build

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, image, push, amazon-ecr

I added new build for my aws code pipline, but the probelm is that the image is not pushed to ecr repository after successful build. I added the same role permissions for this build as for other services and the login to ecr is successful during the build. It makes a lot of retries then EOF appeares and the image is not pushed.

I checked all that the repository url is added to ecr:PutImage action resourses, and checked logs of the build to verify that login to ecr is successful